# How to populate JQuery live search on result click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following segments of a jquery/ajax live search which works great.

I'd like to populate the text input value with the clicked result of the live search.

My attempt doesn't work but I can't figure out why.

**Live Search Form Input**

```
<input type="text" id="vehicle" autocomplete="off" required>

<div class="results">

    <div class="list-group">

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Result 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Result 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">etc...</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">etc...</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Ajax/JQuery In Footer**

```
/// Click to enter result ///
$("#vehicle").keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        if (query != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'path-to-search-script.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.results').html(data);
                    $('.results').css('display', 'block');
                    $("#vehicle").focusout(function () {
                        $('.results').css('display', 'none');
                    });
                    /// Click to enter result ///
                    $(".results a").on("click", function(){
                        $("#vehicle").val($(this).html());
                    });
                    $("#vehicle").focusin(function () {
                        $('.results').css('display', 'block');
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.results').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
```

Comment: This code looks great. Where is the ajax ?

Comment: I've updated the OP to include the ajax.